# react set value to another component when change value in different component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-ref

i have two react input components, where in one input component; value changes, i have to set the same value in another input field.

here is my two input components.

```html
               <div className="col-md-4">
                  <label htmlFor="saleamount">Payment </label>
                  <NumberFormat id="manualPaymentEntry" name="manualPaymentEntry" fixedDecimalScale={true} decimalScale={2} value={manualPayEntry.current} className="form-control" thousandSeparator={true} thousandsGroupStyle="lakh" onChange={(values) => {
                    const { formattedValue, value } = values;
                    handleManualPaymentEntry(value);
                  }} />
                  
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-4">
                  <label htmlFor="selectedPayment">Actual Payment</label>
                  <NumberFormat readOnly={true} fixedDecimalScale={true} decimalScale={2} value={cumulativePay} className="form-control" thousandSeparator={true} thousandsGroupStyle="lakh" />
                </div>
              </div>
```

when there is change in `manualPaymentEntry` i have to set same value to `cumulativePay`

```html
  const [cumulativePay, setCumulativePay] = useState(0);
  const manualPayEntry = useRef(0);


  useEffect(() => {
    setCumulativePay(manualPayEntry.current);
  }, [manualPayEntry]);


const handleManualPaymentEntry = (value) => {
    let val = parseFloat(value);
    manualPayEntry.current = value;
  }
```

i have used useRef for `manualPayEntry`  to set current value to `cumulativePay`, but when there is change in `manualPayEntry`  it is not setting value to `cumulativePay`, always i am getting '0' only..., but current value of `manualPayEntry`  shouled get refelcted in `cumulativePay`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue got resolved, after chaning onChange to onValueChange, as said in the documentation onchange will no longer get value , instead we need to use onValueChange

[react-number-format npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-number-format)

> onValueChange is not same as onChange. It gets called on whenever
> there is change in value which can be caused by any event like change
> or blur event or by a prop change. It no longer receives event object
> as second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Changing a value manually like you are doing it there:

```
manualPayEntry.current = value;
```

Does not trigger the rerendering functionalities of React. Why don't you just add the setCumulativePay directly in the handleManualPaymentEntry?

```
const handleManualPaymentEntry = (value) => {
    let val = parseFloat(value);
    manualPayEntry.current = value;
    setCumulativePay(value);
}
```

Or you should treat manualPayEntry as a state as well and not a ref, though it's not really advised to change a state in a useEffect based on another state. I really think changing directly the needed state in your handler function is the best solution.

Comment: changing directly is not working setCumulativePay(value);, i am getting value as undefined

Comment: Can you check you are using properly the onChange function of your NumberFormat component, seems like undefined is being passed to your handler.

Comment: but my manualPayEntry is working with onChange function. i mean, the value is getting populated in the input box, but i am getting undefined when i debug, hence i started using useRef for manalPayEntry to get current value....

Comment: What do you get if you console.log(value) in your handler function?

Comment: 6  AddCreditTransaction.js:121  manualpayment entry  :::  undefined

Comment: So your onChange function is not sending the proper information. Try to console.log values in the onChange function to see what should be passed

Comment: thanks Ivo, it got solved after chaning onchange to onValueChange...